# Sequential Token Management in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sequence

I am looking for a better solution to achieve following task

I have a table as shown below

```
CouponNo   Status      Sequence
A101      Completed       1
A102      Completed       2
A103      Completed       3
A104      Serving         4
A105      Pending         5
A106      Pending         6
A107      Pending         7
A108      Pending         8
A109      Pending         9
A110      Pending         10
A111      Pending         11
A112      Pending         12
A113      Pending         13
A114      Pending         14
A115      Pending         15
```

I have a case where tokens can be put on hold. Policy says when we resume hold tokens it should be placed after 3 tokens from the currently serving token
In our example lets say A105 and A106 are put on hold. Then the table becomes

```
   CouponNo   Status      Sequence
    A101      Completed       1
    A102      Completed       2
    A103      Completed       3
    A104      Serving         4
    A105      Hold           -99
    A106      Hold           -99
    A107      Pending         5
    A108      Pending         6
    A109      Pending         7
    A110      Pending         8
    A111      Pending         9
    A112      Pending         10
    A113      Pending         11
    A114      Pending         12
    A115      Pending         13
```

Either I put sequence as -99 for all holded tokens or is it better to move them to HOLD table?

secondly when we resume both, i want the table like below

```
      CouponNo   Status      Sequence
        A101      Completed       1
        A102      Completed       2
        A103      Completed       3
        A104      Serving         4
      **A105      Pending         8**
      **A106      Pending         9**            
        A107      Pending         5
        A108      Pending         6
        A109      Pending         7
        A110      Pending         10
        A111      Pending         11
        A112      Pending         12
        A113      Pending         13
        A114      Pending         14
        A115      Pending         15
```

How we can achieve this by creating a common procedure.